# If $E$ open set. Why $\left\{(x,y):x-y\in E\right\}$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Without using that $f(x,y)=x-y$ is continuous.
If $E$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Why $\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x-y\in E\right\}$ is a Lebesgue measurable set? $\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x-y\in E\right\}$ is open set?

Comment: Could you use that rotation of $\Bbb R^2$ by $45°$ is continuous/measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S=\{(x,y)\mid x-y\in E\}$.
Given a point $(a,b)\in S$. 
Then $a-b\in E$, and hence, there is a neighbourhood of $a-b$, say $]a-b-r, a-b+r[\subseteq E$ for some $r>0$. 
Then the open disc with radius $r/2$ aroud the center $(a,b)$ is contained in $S$: if $(x,y)$ is in this disc, then $a-r/2<x<a+r/2$ and $b-r/2<y<b+r/2$, thus $a-b-r<x-y<a-b+r$, hence $x-y\in E$.